# Using Google Drive API for iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk, google-drive-api

How can I download the revision history list of a Google Drive Document (that the user doesn't own) through an iPhone app?

All I am really looking for is the date and time of the last revision.

Comment: A sample was provided by Ali Afshar.  You should use the sample after walking through the instructions provided by grobbins.  Pasting those things here should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [queryForChangesList](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Drive/Generated/GTLQueryDrive.m#89) to return a [GTLDriveChangeList](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Drive/Generated/GTLDriveChangeList.m). There is also [a sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/) for using the API that might help you.

Comment: How do i import the framework? I downloaded it and all but how do I get the app to use it?

Comment: Build instructions are at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary